# What is a correct approach to a javascript monorepo

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, lerna, monorepo

I'm trying to figure out correct approach for a javascript monorepo. Imagine monorepo containing packages / libraries:

```
root
  - node_modules
  - packages
      + lib-a
          * node_modules
      + lib-b
          * node_modules
```

Now let's say both `lib-a` and `lib-b` packages use `webpack` as their build tool.

I see two approaches

1. Add `wepback` as dependency to root. Include "build" script in both packages: `"build": "webpack -p --config webpack.config.js`. `webpack.config.js` could include root `webpack.config.js`. Then I could use tool like `lerna` to run the build from root directory (which means `webpack` binary is recognized. However I will be unable to run the build in specific packages since `webpack` is not available there. I could probably change the build script to something like `"build": "../../node_modules/.bin/webpack -p --config webpack.config.js`
2. Always include `webpack` in each package. This means that `build` script will succeed. This also means that each package will have the same dependency and I should probably watch that each package uses same `webpack` version.

Basically what I'm getting at is how should packages inside monorepo be structured? If any package is published, should it always be possible to `build` that package separately.

Comment: The way our mono repo works is each packages has their own node-modules but you can install only the ones that interest you and you are working on. We then have a command Build at root which basically executes build in all packages

Comment: So you are putting the responsibility of building onto the "root" package and run build commands from there.
That seems like the correct approach. I'm thinking to do this for rest of the commands as well (such as testing, clean-up etc.).

Comment: You should look into **lerna**. It has tools to help you manage a monorepo and also automate certain tasks like linking the packages within your monorepo. I use lerna for my monorepo and it works beautifully.

Comment: I think it would make sense to change the title of this question to something like "What is a correct approach to a javascript monorepo". This would help others to find this question/answer when searching through Stackoverflow/Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach #2 is right. You handle each package separately as it was an individual, self-contained package.

The advantage of a monorepo lays not in sharing files through the directory structure but in:

1. Bootstrapping all dependencies to a single `node_modules` with flat structure, effectively deduplicating them.
2. Making your packages available to your other packages through regular package `import`/`require()` as they were external dependencies. And, thanks to symlinks to `node_modules`, your "dependency" packages contain always the latest content without publishing.
3. Enforcing consistent, always up-to-date, dependency structure in all your packages. As you said "This also means that each package will have the same dependency".
4. Automation tools to perform different maintainance tasks (like build, publish) on all your packages with a single command.

I know it's not so easy at the beginning, but when you dig into Lerna documentation it's becoming more clear. Besides Lerna [main page](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) I recommend reading about [hoisting](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/blob/master/doc/hoist.md), [FAQ](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/blob/master/FAQ.md) and individual commands like [bootstrap](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/bootstrap) and [publish](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/publish).

Comment: I second everything here. Each package should be able to build and test itself on its own. I recommend yarn workspaces + lerna, but it's not necessary. We created root-level tsconfig and jest config which are imported/extended by individual packages. We also let the root take care of linting for all packages, `husky` for pre-commit hooks, and `commitizen` for consistent commit messages.

Answer (score 1):

Our current configuration is same as you:

```
root
  - node_modules
  - packages
      + lib-a
          * node_modules
      + lib-b
          * node_modules
```

We use **lerna** to handle our project: https://github.com/lerna/lerna

You just need to specify your package folder in the `lerna.json`

```
{
  "lerna": "3.16.4",
  "packages": ["packages/*"],
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "npmClient": "yarn",
  "useWorkspaces": true
}
```

Then in your `package.json` scripts you can use the line:

```
"build": "lerna run build",
```

This will basically run a build in all packages. So as long as your build script in each package has the proper params and webpack installed it will automatically run the webpack build.

After that you can simply handle working in your designated packages.